# Algorithm Analysis for Bubble Sort

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity, bubble-sort

Given the following procedure (pseudocode) for Bubble Sort, I'm trying to calculate the Ω notation.

```
procedure BUBBLE_SORT(A,n) {
    array A(1 to n)
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++) {
            if(A[j] > A[j+1] {
                //swap(A(j), A(j+1))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) || C1 = n+1 (because it still checks when it is false)

for(int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++) || C2 = (n)(n+1) (you multiply n+1 since it is nested?)

if(A[j] > A[j+1]) || C3 = 1

This would give me:

C1(n+1) + C2(n^2 + n) + C3

And wouldn't this be equal to Ω(n^2)? But I know that for Bubble Sort, it should be Ω(n) (if the list is sorted already).

What's wrong with my computation?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you taking advantage of the fact that it is 'sorted already'?  That would seem to be the key point....

Comment: If it were sorted already, wouldn't it still have to run through the code?

Answer (score 2):

it is in Ω(n), because of the best case when the elements are already sorted where Ω(n) denotes the lower bound of the complexity.

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
   int i, j;
   bool swapped;
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
   {
     swapped = false;
     for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
     {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
        {
           swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
           swapped = true;
        }
     }

     // IF no two elements were swapped by inner loop, then break
     if (swapped == false)
        break;
   }
}
```

If we use the code above, we can see that we can check if a swap occurred or not, incase no swap had occurred that means it is already sorted hence we can break the loop in 1 iteration

Comment: Is there a way to prove this mathematically? (like what I did with C1, C2, C3).

Comment: Ah, I get why it's Ω(n) from your code :o My problem is that my professor gave us that pseudocode to analyze. So, does that mean his pseudocode, without a check to see if a swap occurred, does not run on Ω(n)?